# curl в цикле, повторить если 500

Tags: curl, cmd, bat, if

Всем привет!

Отправляю CURL POST, иногда возвращается 500 и выходной файл пустой.

Я могу прочитать после этого файл.

Вопрос: Могу ли я отправить повторно запрос установив какой-то флаг или вернуться назад по метке?

Код выполняется в цикле, вот пример:

`for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%cd%\txt\example.txt) do (curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept-Charset: UTF-8" -d "My_JSON" https://MeWebsite --output "%cd%\txt\Result.txt" ...)`

Возможны 3 варианта Result.txt (JSON):

1. **Пустой** файл (потому что не отправился запрос), нужно **повторить запрос на данном этапе цикла**;
2. Файл заполнен **ненужным** для меня ответом, можно **перейти в конец цикла**, чтобы начался новый этап;
3. Файл заполнен **нужным** для меня ответом, нужно **продолжить остальные команды** `...`.

Comment: Внутри цикла создать метку. Есть команда IF, проверяющая условие и переходящая по этой метке (в начало итерации, например). Есть способ определить файл пустой или нет (погуглите: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225581/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-not-empty-in-batch). А вот определить нужный или ненужный контент в файле, это уже сильно зависит от содержания.

Comment: @NoSkill, спасибо, я уже решил проблему. Главная задача была перезапустить запрос, если возвращается 500. Разобрался с мануалом, осилил его. Решило `--retry`. А остальное я просто читаю нужный фрагмент строки файла и перехожу по `goto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Осилил мануал, но информацию сложно было найти в интернете.

Мало ли кому понадобится, то оставлю этот вопрос.

Если `curl` возвращает 500, то установить флаг `--retry <число>`. Данный флаг повторит попытку